only one column of the DataGridViewComboBox is filled in
12 TabControls are created on the forum, inside each DataGridView, inside which there are 5 DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. I wrote a method that should fill in all DataGridViewComboBoxColumn. However, when the program starts, only the very first column on the first TabControl is filled in
method of creating a TabControl
 private void InitializeTab()
        {
            tab = new TabControl();

            tab.Size = new Size((System.Drawing.Point)this.Size);


            for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
            {
                TabPage tp = new TabPage(Convert.ToString(i + 1));
                DataGridView Grid = CreateDataGridView(i+1);
                tp.Controls.Add(Grid);
                tab.TabPages.Add(tp);

            }

            this.Controls.Add(tab);

            Controls.Add(tab);
            tab.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, menuStrip1.Bottom);
        }

The method of creating a DataGridView
private DataGridView CreateDataGridView(int classNumber)
        {
            DataGridView dataGridView = new DataGridView();
            dataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            DataGridViewTextBoxColumn rowNumerColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            rowNumerColumn.HeaderText = "#";
            dataGridView.Columns.Add(rowNumerColumn);


            for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
            {
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                {
                    DataGridViewComboBoxColumn subjectColumn = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
                    subjectColumn.HeaderText = daysOfWeek[i / 2];
                    dataGridView.Columns.Add(subjectColumn);

                    string tableName;
                    if (classNumber>=1 && classNumber <=4)
                        tableName = "Disciplines1_4";
                    else if (classNumber >= 5 && classNumber <= 9)
                        tableName = "Disciplines5_9";
                    else
                        tableName = "Disciplines10_11";

                    Dictionary<int, List<string>> headers = GetDisciplinesHeaders(connectString, tableName, classNumber); //There's a mistake somewhere
                    if (headers.ContainsKey(i + 1))
                    {
                        foreach (string header in headers[i + 1])
                        {
                            subjectColumn.Items.Add(header);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn roomColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
                    roomColumn.HeaderText = "кабинет";
                    dataGridView.Columns.Add(roomColumn);
                }
            }


            return dataGridView;
        }

The GetDisciplinesHeaders() method accesses the DB and returns a dictionary. There are definitely no problems in it, I checked it with a debugger
